# Can I restrict a function to be pure in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, pure-function

Is there a way to allow a function to be [pure](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/) only (thus not accepting the function to be non pure) in TypeScript? If yes, which?

Comment: you decide if a function is a pure function. not typescript..

Comment: Here is an article: https://vsavkin.com/functional-typescript-316f0e003dc6

Comment: @Roman Ideally a proper type system should be able to do purity analysis. Of course TypeScript isn't that

Comment: At the moment there is only an open issue on GitHub discussing the possibility to add a `pure` modifier: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7770

Comment: @Bergi yeah that was my idea.. I am just learning TS now, that's why I am asking..Thanks for the link and all the comments. Stephan yes, I had seen that, but I was asking if there was something standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be able to write a few TSLint rules to catch most of the common cases (access to outside variables, for example), but checking something like that is nigh impossible, so there's no way to actually know 100%.

You (and your team) still have to be disciplined.

Comment: Function purity detection doesn't need to solve the halting problem.

Comment: The answer doesn't seem to be correct. Citation?
At the very least, it's possible to detect a subset of cases in which a function is pure, and mark as "impure" when the compiler can't tell one way or another. Voting down, but will undo the downvote if there is a good link and/or explanation.

Comment: You may think that `const getX = obj => obj.x` is pure for example, but I can still pass `{ get x() { doSideEffect(); return 42; } }`, you can't win, not in JavaScript.

Comment: The kind of object you pass to that pure function does not make it impure. That would make all lodash functions like _.forEach, _.map impure, but they are not. They are all pure. If you cause a side effect in the callback function, the callback is impure, but the _.map and _.forEach functions themselves are not impure.